# font-awesome icons will not transition transform:rotate(180deg)

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I'd like the downward arrows on my mobile menu to rotate 180 degrees and face up on click. I'd also like to animate the rotation for a smooth transition. I am using Javascript to toggle a ".js-rotate" class on my ".fa-angle-down" font-awesome class.

The last line in the JS function controls this behavior:

```
nav.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('nav-list-drawer__btn')) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('js-nav-list-drawer__btn');
    e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('js-nav-list-drawer__list');
    e.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('js-nav-list-drawer');
    e.target.firstChild.classList.toggle('js-rotate'); // breaks  on IE11. Place last so code before it is parsed before the entire function breaks and pauses
  }
});
```

I've tried adding a "transition: transform 1s;" to ".fa-angle-down", but am having no luck.

The CSS is available via sass/components/_navigation.scss on the following link: https://codepen.io/eliya33/project/editor/XpgvJo

Comment: Not sure how to duplicate a codepen project or make it not read-only

Comment: Does it have to be JS, can you use CSS?

Comment: Ah. Totally understandable since I'm not sure either haha.

Comment: The JS is for toggling a class for the rotate animation onlick, but I would be interested in a pure CSS solution--not sure how it would control onclick behavior though.

Comment: @Jordan.J.D You can fork it in the top menu.

Comment: @noddy an "onclick" option isn't possible for CSS, only :active and :focus, but that's not what you want. I came up with [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/SirExotic/30bq4jn5/3/), but for some reason the rotate doesn't work, but expand does. Anyone have a fix to this?

Comment: @SirExotic Your problem is the same as mine. Hope someone solves it haha. I tried adding "transition: transform 1s;" to ".button" but the transition surprisingly doesn't work

Comment: @ROKAF I think I got it, answer is below :)

Comment: @Sir Exotic I added "transition: transform 1s;" to ".rotate" and it works now! https://jsfiddle.net/30bq4jn5/8/ Still can't figure out why mine didn't work when I tried the same tactic though...

Comment: That would fire the transition every time you click on the button, so if it's already rotated, it's going to start over at 0deg and rotate back to 180deg, not the other way around. You can probably see what is happening there. Check out my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I used **jQuery** to fire the *onclick* function, and **CSS** to apply the transition effect. I think this works flawless.

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  $("#arrow").toggleClass("rotate");
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.button {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#arrow {
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;;
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
  <i id="arrow" class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-2x"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm still not working with mine. Ugh brain's too fried to work. Thank you for the answer though : )

Comment: Yes your code snippet works fine, it's just when I apply the same principles, my problem still persists.

Comment: I cannot load the .scss files when I fork your project, so unfortunately I can't dig deeper into the problem, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The answers posted here seem to resolve the common issues associated with transitioning simple transforms. My case still remains unresolved for reasons unknown but will select this question as answered anyways since the offered solutions should work for most cases.